# How to pass different type struct as parameter to a function,in Golang

Tags: go

I have a function for decode http response json to a struct.And I have two types of structs needed to pass to this function, and have the type of struct as return value to get the decoded json.

My function now can deal with ONE type, need help to make it can handle different type of struct, and return the struct.

```golang
// Response json
type responseResult struct {
    result string
}

type loginResult struct {
    responseResult
    token string
}

func responseBodyDecoder(resp http.Response,response *responseResult) {
    // get result form Response
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    decode_err := decoder.Decode(&response)
    if decode_err != nil {
        panic(decode_err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use type `interface{}`:

```
func responseBodyDecoder(resp http.Response,response interface{}) {
    // get result form Response
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    decode_err := decoder.Decode(response)
    if decode_err != nil {
        panic(decode_err)
    }
}
```

now, you can:

```
ret:=loginResult{}
responseBodyDecoder(resp, &ret)

ret2:=responseResult{}
responseBodyDecoder(resp, &ret2)
```

but careful, both struct `responseResult` and `responseResult` don't export any element.
you must modify the definition:

```
type responseResult struct {
    Result string
}
```